# expand width of tcolorbox for dynamic section titles in memoir latex

Tags: sectioning, memoir, tcolorbox

I am looking to use tcolorbox for styling dynamic section titles. My problem is that I want the box to span the entire width of the paragraph bellow it and have the text centred if possible. I've done my best to provide a MWE of my problem but I am pretty new to this so feel free to suggest changes to my example if needed.

**The Code:**

```
%!TeX encoding = utf8
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,openbib,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,most,listings,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text only
\checkandfixthelayout

\newtcbox{\mybox}{
    nobeforeafter
}
\makepagestyle{MyBox}
\makeheadstyles{MyBox}{
    \setsecheadstyle{\mybox}
}
\headstyles{MyBox}

\begin{document}
 \section*{Introduction}
 \lipsum[2]
 \section*{Methods}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Which gives:**

[image]

Comment: A `tcbox` is exactly as wide as the content as it, plus some separation distance to the frame. You need the `tcolorbox`environment, which has the width of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The `\tcbox` is the wrong tool for this, since it fixes the width to the width of the content and does not use the width of the text.

Use a wrapper macro for a `tcolorbox` environment instead and say `valign=center,halign=center,nobeforeafter`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,openbib,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,most,listings,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text only
\checkandfixthelayout

\newtcolorbox{myboxstuff}[1][]{code={\parindent=0em},left skip=0pt,valign=center,nobeforeafter,halign=center,#1}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
\begin{myboxstuff}
#1
\end{myboxstuff}%
}
\makepagestyle{MyBox}
\makeheadstyles{MyBox}{
    \setsecheadstyle{\mybox}
}
\headstyles{MyBox}

\begin{document}
 \section*{Introduction}
 \lipsum[2]
 \section*{Methods}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @bthorne: Happy TeXing...