# \section doesn't work within a tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, memoir

I am a teacher and trying to create a file where I collect everything I do on a whiteboard as a reference.

To do so, I wanted to use [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=de) for different parts of my lessons. I also want the top of the page to show, what lesson it belongs to, incase I need to mix something up later.

However using `\section{}` within the tcolorbox somehow isn't transfered to `\rightmark`

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%Font
\usepackage{cmbright}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Head
\makepagestyle{myheader}
    \makeevenhead{myheader}{}{\itshape\textbf{\rightmark}}{}
    \makeoddhead{myheader} {}{\itshape\textbf{\rightmark}}{}
    \makeheadrule{myheader}{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\pagestyle{myheader}

%Box
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins}

\begin{document}
    \section{This appears on the top}
    
    Test
    \vfill
    \pagebreak
    
    \tcolorbox
    \section{This doesn't}
    Test
    \endtcolorbox
    
    \pagebreak
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

output:
[image: Section outside the box, page 1]

[image: Section inside the box, page 2]

[image: TableOfContents, for reference]

**Update (2023-08-29):** from the current answers it doesn't seem able to do this,  since `\sectionmark` called inside a tcolorbox isn't passed out. I opened an issue over on github [here](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/242) and will update this post, if there is a solution given.

Update: This is not possible to fix, since [mark commands don‘t leave boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557302/128801), as stated by wueb and Alan.
Both solutions given are workarounds with sectionmark and limitations as pointed out by Alan.

Comment: Related: [\markboth inside tikz \node text not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509817/markboth-inside-tikz-node-text-not-working)

Comment: @Sk1nk See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471583/expand-width-of-tcolorbox-for-dynamic-section-titles-in-memoir-latex for a solution (perhaps) more integrated in `memoir`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sophanatprime read my problem over at github and presented a solution with a selfcreated package [at the tcolorbox issues](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/242#issuecomment-1700236266).

After manually installing their package, `\usepackage[tcolorbox]{updatemarks}` solves the problem (for up to two sections per box).

The package itself can be found on [their github](https://github.com/Sophanatprime/updatemarks).

Edit: The package is now available via tlmgr.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an elegant solution, but it works.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makepagestyle{myheader}
    \makeevenhead{myheader}{}{\rightmark}{}
    \makeoddhead{myheader} {}{\rightmark}{}
    \makeheadrule{myheader}{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\pagestyle{myheader}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
Test
\newpage

\begin{tcolorbox}[before=\sectionmark{Section title in tcolorbox}\noindent]
\section{Section title in tcolorbox}
Test
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only appears to solve the problem in this specific instance. Try adding another section within the box...

Comment: Another problem is, that this isn't transfered if one creates prestyled tcolorboxes. For example: I got a box for my motivation:
```\newtcolorbox{motivation}[1]{enhanced, colback = Yellow!25 , colbacktitle = Yellow!10, coltitle = black, colframe = Yellow, title =  {Motivation ({#1}):}}```
but `\begin{motivation}[before=\sectionmark{Section title in tcolorbox}\noindent]` doesn't work. So I would need another placeholder, wich causes it's one kind of problems, if I don't want a section-title, because it uses the first letter then.
Edit: formating

Comment: If I can not get the section out of the tcolorbox, is there an other way to get the name of the current section, besides `\leftmark` (chapter) and `\rightmark `(section)? For example, there has to be a solution for onesided documents, but I am not able to find one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `\sectionmark` is not set properly when calling (or eaten by) your tcolorbox, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557302/122071).

Edit: Adding a global counter which is called when defining a new section works if *one* section is called within a `\tcolorbox`.

But due to the limitations (see above), using multiple sections in one box, then still only the last section title called will be added on all pages displaying this specific `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{cmbright}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
    
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mySectionHead[1]{%
  \xdef\@thisheader{%
    #1
  }
}
\mySectionHead{}

%Header
\makepagestyle{myheader}
    \makeevenhead{myheader}{}{\textbf{\@thisheader}}{}
    \makeoddhead{myheader}{}{\textbf{\@thisheader}}{}
    \makeheadrule{myheader}{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\pagestyle{myheader}
\makeatother

\newcommand\mysection[1]{%
    \mySectionHead{#1}
    \section{#1}
}

%Box
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins}

\newtcolorbox{testbox}[1][]{%
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    #1
}
\newcommand*{\fakebreak}{\par\vspace{\textheight minus \textheight}\pagebreak}
    
\begin{document}
    \section{This appears on the top}
    
    Test
    \vfill
    \pagebreak
    
    \tcolorbox
    \section{This doesn't}
    Test
    \endtcolorbox
    
    \pagebreak
    \begin{testbox}[title=Testbox]
        \mysection{This does}
        \lipsum[1-10]
        
        \fakebreak
        
        \mysection{This does as well}
        \lipsum[1]  
    \end{testbox}

    \pagebreak
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this assumes that the `tcolorbox` just contains the section, but my understanding of the OP's question is that the `tcolorbox` can span multiple sections and the headers should update accordingly (which I don't think is possible).

Comment: I think I cloud make this work, because for this to fail it would require the tcolorbox to span multiple pages with multiple section within the tcolorbox. But as Alan stated, it has it's limits.

Comment: True, the `\sectionmark`should be called before the `\section` is defined, it the latter spans multiple pages. Concering multiple section in one box, also don't think it's possible, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557302/122071

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

% Define custom section title format
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{}
[\sectionmark{\thesection\quad#1}]

% Define custom box environment
\newenvironment{coloredbox}{%
  \mdfsetup{
    skipabove=1em,
    skipbelow=1em,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    rightmargin=0pt,
    linecolor=black,
    backgroundcolor=gray!20,
    linewidth=0.5pt,
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    innerrightmargin=10pt,
    innertopmargin=6pt,
    innerbottommargin=6pt,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    singleextra={\sectionmark{\leftmark}}
  }
  \begin{mdframed}%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}

\pagestyle{myheader} % Use the previously defined page style

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
Test
\newpage

\begin{coloredbox}
\section{Section title in colored box}
Test
\end{coloredbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that titlesec should generally not be used with memoir

Comment: And like the other answers, this doesn't actually solve the problem; it creates a section that is boxed, but the OP's question is about sections inside boxes that are larger than sections.